# Why the file name has renamed partially?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have tried to rename all the filenames using batch script. But the file names are changed partially with previous filename when I am using the below script.

**Batch:**

```
@ECHO OFF
Title Renamer
color 1a
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set HR=%time:~0,2%
set HR=%Hr: =0% 
set HR=%HR: =%
echo Filenames are renaming by this user %USERNAME% in %ComputerName% @ %USERDOMAIN%
ECHO.
ECHO.
set /p input=Enter Your Path: 
set /p ext=Ext: 
set /p rename=Rename with: 
cd /d %input%
set i=0
FOR %%F IN (%ext%) DO (
    set /a i=i+1
    ren %%F %rename%_!i!%ext%
)
ECHO Filenames are renaming by this user %USERNAME% in %ComputerName% @ %USERDOMAIN% on Date: %date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4% Time: %HR%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% Source Folder: %input% Extension: %ext% Rename with: %rename% >> renamed_by-%USERNAME%-%ComputerName%_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%HR%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.log
```

**Output:**

```
Enter Your Path: d:\pathtochange\
Ext: *.xhtml
Rename with: chapter
```

**Input filenames are:**

```
chap_01_intro.xhtml
chap_01.xhtml
chap_02.xhtml
chap_03.xhtml
chap_04_intro.xhtml
chap_04.xhtml
chap_05.xhtml
```

But after the execute the script, the output shows

```
chapter_1.xhtml
chapter_2ntro.xhtml
chapter_3.xhtml
chapter_4.xhtml
chapter_5.xhtml
chapter_6ntro.xhtml
chapter_7.xhtml
```

But I want the filenames should be changed

```
chapter_1.xhtml
chapter_2.xhtml
chapter_3.xhtml
chapter_4.xhtml
chapter_5.xhtml
chapter_6.xhtml
chapter_7.xhtml
```

Why it's renamed like this?

How to find the filenames rename it by user prompt?

Comment: What do you expect to happen to the _intro files?

Comment: Just find `(.*?).xhtml` (any user extension) and replace with `$1.xhtml` the user input whatever it may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete sample:

```vb
set /p "input= Enter your path: " 
set /p "suffix= Enter the suffix extension you want to search and rename (i.e. .TXT) : "

rem :: remove dot in suffix
set suffix=%suffix:.=%

set /p "prefix= Enter the word you want to use to rename: "

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set increment=0
FOR /R %input% %%a in (*.%suffix%) do (
    set /a increment+=1
    echo rename %%a %prefix%_!increment!%%~xa
)
endlocal
```

Note: remove `echo` command in front of `rename` if it's Okay

---

```vb
@echo off

rem :: set undo to true if you need to generate a reverse batch file.
set "undo=true"
set "logfile=true"


for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set /p "input= Enter your path: " 
set /p "suffix= Enter the suffix extension you want to search and rename (i.e. .TXT) : "

rem :: remove dot in suffix
set suffix=%suffix:.=%

set /p "prefix= Enter the word you want to use to rename: "
set "timestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%-%HH%%Min%%Sec%"

if /i "%undo%"=="true" (
  echo @echo off
  echo rem :: user: %USERNAME%
  echo rem :: Date: %DATE% %TIME%
  echo rem :: Source folder: %input%
  echo rem :: Extension: %suffix:.=%
  echo rem :: renamed to: %prefix%
  echo rem :: to undo file renaming: undo-renaming-%timestamp%.bat
)>undo-renaming-%timestamp%.bat

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set increment=0
(
  for /r %input% %%a in (*.%suffix%) do (
    set /a increment+=1
    echo The file: "%%a" was renamed to "%prefix%_!increment!%%~xa"
    rename "%%a" "%prefix%_!increment!%%~xa"
    if "%undo%"=="true" (
       echo rename "%%~dpa%prefix%_!increment!%%~xa" "%%~nxa"
    )>>undo-renaming-%timestamp%.bat
  )
)>reverse-rename-%timestamp%.log
if /i "%logfile%" neq "true" del reverse-rename-%timestamp%.log

endlocal
```

Note: In the final script, we can push the scenario farther and check if the file Undo is present and then make restoration automatically.

Comment: `xxxxxxxx_1.xhtml` did not renamed after run the `undo-renaming-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx.bat`

Comment: by the way can you remove obselete comments pls

Comment: Thanks and sorry, but i can give upvote after 15 reputation. really appreciate for it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely to be caused by the fact that the destination name in your `ren` command contains a wildcard (from `%ext%).

I'd suggest having the user enter just the extension (i.e. `xhtml` rather than `*.xhtml`) then add the necessary wildcard in the `FOR` command only.

Alternatively you could use `%%~xF` instead of `%ext%` in the `ren` command which should achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks @Iridium. it works cool. When i execute the script in first time, it changed good `_1, _2...._n`,  but the file names are changed `_2..._n` in the 2nd hit. i think, it has `%rename%_!i!` increment. why its happened?